# Angular development server doesn't work the same as Angular production server

Tags: angular, web-development-server

I am fairly new to development and am working on an Angular project Which I have inherited from someone else.

I am currently trying to set up a development server and so, I copied all the build files generated using the ng build --prod (Angular command) from the production server and imported them to the development server.

After some apache configuration and making some changes to my hosts file, I tried entering the page i.e. pages.100pins.com which went well and everything seems to work.
[home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boFrm.png)

But when i tried to change the url to pages.100pins.com/client/lrr/login, The requested URL /client/lrr/login was not found on this server.[couldn't find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grj7p.png)

But the same url works fine when routed to the production server . [picture of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f4Da.png)

I feel that I am missing some critical element here but couldn't find any solution for this.

I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure Apache properly to allow deep linking in an angular application. You could create a .htaccess file and put it into angular's public directory (where the index.html lies)

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also refer to: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: I added this and the application no longer says that The requested URL /client/lrr/login was not found on this server but is getting redirected to the the pages.100pins.com and is showing a blank page

Comment: Maybe you have changed some other configuration for apache and your hosts file. I don't know then why it is not working. I have deployed many angular applications and if you have the apache server with default config, it always worked fine. May be check your hosts file configuration. I dont think it is necessary to configure that